# Qt5 добавление библиотеки в проект под Windows

Tags: qt5, lib

не получается добавить библиотеку в проект. Как добавляю: по имени проекта ПКМ-добавить библиотеку-внешняя-платформа Windows-Компоновка Статическая-снять галочку добавить суффикс

Либ и хедеры лежат в корне, в .pro файл добавляются строки

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -ldln
 
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
 
win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./dln.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./libdln.a
```

При сборке появляется несколько ошибок формата:

skipping incompatible *путь к проекту*/libdln.a when searching for -ldln

/libdln.a в ошибках чередуется с /dln.lib и /dln.dll

Windows7 x64, Qt 5.12.11 MinGW 64-bit

Как решить проблему? Заранее благодарю.

Имеются файлы в корне:

- dln.dll
- dln.h
- dln.lib
- dln.net.dll
- libdln.a

  - несколько .h

Как будет корректно прописать, если прописывать вручную?

Comment: скорее всего Ваши либы 32битные

Comment: Библиотека C++ или C? Скомпилирована или скачана?

Comment: Библиотека c++, поставляется производителем оборудования